# How to hide the notifications of the Teamviewer (silent use) in Computer and Android phones

Tags: android, teamviewer, remote-control

Is it possible to hide a quick panel of the TeamViewer in the right corner and other notifications and pop-ups to enable a "silent" remote session?

While using team viewer Host application in android phone(remote phone) and connected to that device , the host application is showing a permanent notification in remote phone as long as connection ends. How to disable that notification? (Not able to disable in settings>apps. Turn off notification is not found for teamviewer host app)

Comment: Is it possible now in the new 7.0 version commercial or non-comersion version?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under the TeamViewer Options, Advanced, enable "Automatically minimize local TeamViewer Panel".

Other than that, there is no way that allows you to do so; it would otherwise be a security concern...

[image]

Comment: How to open team viewer options?

Comment: @JimThio: It depends on the version, it is usually found in one of the menus at the top.

Comment: What's the security concern if you're remotely monitoring a fleet of your own computers?

Comment: @AYS: How much do you trust TeamViewer as a company? You rely on their security. If you don't want that, you have to set up some RDP / VNC / ... solution.

Comment: I think he used the wrong word (not security concern) but a privacy concern.  if they person being monitored doesn't know they are being watched, its then a leak of privacy. not a security leak. but i see his point.

Comment: This does not answer the original question, because even minimized you can still see the side tab sticking out. therefore this is not the solution asked for.  how this got 24 ticks i will never know.

Comment: The mentioned notification by the question is hidden, as to remove the annoyance on the mobile screen. It is a security concern, not a leak, when there would be no informed indication of a remote session. It's like going aboard a ship: You have to write down your name such that people know you are there, regardless of their privacy.