# Prevent TeamViewer Startup Popup on Windows 7 Guest Account

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer, guest-account

I have a computer that is in a meeting room.  The guest account is used by staff logging onto it.  However, every time a member of staff logs onto the guest account, they get the TeamViewer host popup.

On normal account this only appears the first time a user logs on after TeamViewer installation.  On the guest account it happens every time.  Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Adjust what applications are started when I user logs in this will require administrator permissions

Comment: login as an administrator, run "msconfig" click on the "Startup" tab and uncheck TeamViewer related services?

Comment: Login as guest user, let Team Viewer open.. Go to Settings and untick the 'start with windows' option.

Comment: I still want TeamViewer to run - I just don't want it to display the popup box.  This normally only displays the first time TeamViewer is installed, but on the Guest account, it is displaying every time the account is logged into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this is a years late response, please forgive me as no one else has answered this question properly.

Yes there is a way to do this. Contrary to what others have indicated, TeamViewer allows this from the ADVANCED options menu.

**Go to:**

> **EXTRAS >> OPTIONS >> ADVANCED** tab

**Then scroll to:**

> **"Advanced Settings for Computers and Contacts"**
>
> Uncheck **"Show Computers & Contacts on Startup"**

Please see screenshot attached below:

[image: TeamViewer Options Menu Example]

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're talking about this option?
[How to hide the notifications of the Teamviewer (silent use)](https://superuser.com/questions/149724/how-to-hide-the-notifications-of-the-teamviewer-silent-use)

I'm also guessing your guest account probably isn't saving the settings (permissions thing?), so my next thought is finding the right registry keys to copy to the guest account.

Just tried playing around with that setting on my install, and it looks like it's modifying this entry: 
[HKEY_USERS\(MY_USER_ACCT)\Software\TeamViewer]

Here's what checking/unchecking is playing with in mine: "AutoHideServerControl"=dword:00000001 (that's checked)

So I'm thinking find that setting in your profile, and re-create it in the guest account's profile.

Note: This is Registry, so MODIFY AT OWN RISK!

Answer (score 1):

- Remove it from the Windows Startup

  - Login as Administrator
  - Press "Win+R" or the Winduws button and click "Run"
  - Type "msconfig" (without the quotes)
  - Go to "Startup"
  - Uncheck everything connected to TeamViewer
  - Apply and Reboot
- In case this doesn't work

  - Check the Autostart folder of the guest user
  - Remove Teamviewer
- In case it still doesn't work

  - Login as Guest
  - Check the Teamviewer Settings
  - Select "Do not start with Windows"

Answer (score 1):

I made custom application for windows based TeamViewer that closes all annoying windows like Commercial use suspected, Sponsored session etc.

Its running on .NET 4 Framework. So if you are a WinXP user, please install before launch.

I am posting [link for download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61e3jlayvlwiekk/TeamViewer%20Popup%20Blocker.rar?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

I've found on some computers that the MSCONFIG option works for TeamViewer, other times you actually have to disable it in the services. The process is pretty similar:

~ Win+R and type `services.msc`
~ Sort by name and/or simply find the one named TeamViewer
~ RightClick > Properties > Change "Startup type" from "automatic" to Manual/Diasbled > Click "Apply"

If you disable this service TeamViewer will still work fine you will just have to start it manually.
 Keep in mind however that TeamViewer has to be running on the target computer in order to remote into it. This isn't an issue depending on how easily accessible the computer is. However, it is setup this way by default to allow for more remote (require less physical access) features like logging in and connecting to computer profiles.